# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-4

I get this error when I do php artisan migrate. Is there something wrong in my migration files? Or is it possible my models are wrong coded? But the migrations should work even there is something wrong in the models?

```
[Exception]                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'festival_aid.#sql-  
  16643_2033' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `gigs` add constraint gigs_band_  
  id_foreign foreign key (`band_id`) references `bands` (`band_id`) on delete  
   cascade) (Bindings: array (                                                 
  ))

[PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'festival_aid.#sql-  
  16643_2033' (errno: 150)
```

gigs migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gigs', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('gig_id');

            $table->dateTime('gig_startdate');

            $table->integer('band_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('stage_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('band_id')
                ->references('band_id')->on('bands')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('stage_id')
                ->references('stage_id')->on('stages')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('gigs', function($table)
        {
            Schema::drop('gigs');
            $table->dropForeign('gigs_band_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('gigs_stage_id_foreign');
        });
    }
```

bands migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bands', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('band_id');

            $table->string('band_name');
            $table->text('band_members');
            $table->string('band_genre');
            $table->dateTime('band_startdate');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('bands', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            Schema::drop('bands');
        });
    }
```

Model Band

```
<?php

class Band extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'band_id';

    public function gig()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Gig', 'band_id', 'band_id');
    }
}
```

Model Gig

```
<?php

class Gig extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'gig_id';

    public function gig()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Band', 'band_id', 'band_id');
    }

    public function stage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Stage', 'stage_id', 'stage_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You must first create the table, then create the foreign keys:

```
Schema::create('gigs', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('gig_id');

    $table->dateTime('gig_startdate');

    $table->integer('band_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('stage_id')->unsigned();
});

Schema::table('gigs', function($table)
{
    $table->foreign('band_id')
        ->references('band_id')->on('bands')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('stage_id')
        ->references('stage_id')->on('stages')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

And your `bands` table should migrate first, since the `gigs` is referencing it.

Comment: Ok I did this :) still get the same error. I updated my question with my models.

Comment: Is bands migrated? Or none was? Bands should migrate first, since gigs references it.

Comment: That was it. I changed the prefix of the migration files.

Comment: Yep, you need to check the order of migration files

Comment: I don't know if this was an old requirement, but as of 5.0 you can include the foreign commands within the create callback.

Answer (score 16):

While this doesn't apply to OP, others might have this issue:

From the bottom of the [Laravel Schema docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema):

> Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned.

You can do this via `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` when creating your table in the migration file.

Took me a few minutes to realize what was happening.

Comment: This was the answer , I wonder how this magic note not popular .

Answer (score 3):

For those whom other answers doesn't help, the same error throws also when you try to use `'SET_NULL'` action on non-nullable column.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [Andrew](/users/1569679/andrew) by making the reference on the table as this:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing of the above worked for me !
But this did : I just changed integer to unsignedInteger

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 1):

for those who are still having this issue, make sure the field you setting as foreign key is a primary key or should be unique since a foreign key can only be a primary or unique field. 
see sample below

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('username',25)->unique();
 });

Schema::create('another_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name', 25);
   $table->foreign('name')->references('username')->on('users')
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $table->integer('band_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('stage_id')->unsigned();
```

In laravel 5.8, the users_table uses bigIncrements('id') data type for the primary key. So that when you want to refer a foreign key constraint your band_id,stage_id  column needs to be unsignedBigInteger('stage_id')  and band_id type.

The manager also tested this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
You must use bigInteger to solve this problem:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general foreign key issue error.  For me I got it when I switched the arguments in the `references` and `on` methods.  I had:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('users')->on('id');
```

instead of:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem by making pointing to Laravel that the field is **unique** using `unique()`.

Example:

```
Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            /* This fields serves as foriegn key on functions 
            table and it must follow the database **key rules**
            by being unique */
            $table->string('branch_code')->unique();
            $table->string('branch_name');
            $table->string('branch_address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Functions table:

```
    Schema::create('functions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('branch_code');
        $table->string('function');
        $table->timestamps();
        //Reference to branch_code on branches table
        $table->foreign('branch_code')->references('branch_code')->on('branches');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed in config/database `'engine' => 'InnoDB',` to `'engine' => null,` and works

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('users')->on('id');
```

BigInt has datatype of bigint(20) but integer has datatype of int(10). Though both of those are unsigned integer, 'Length/Values' does not match.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 6.X use this format.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('dest_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('dest_id')->references('id')->on('destinations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing from:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unique();
```

To:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key must use either unsignedInterger or unsignedBigInterger

exam:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->string('post_type');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on update" properties of the constraint:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
  ->constrained()
  ->onUpdate('cascade')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkout the referenced tables , for example you could get such errors if you pass the values . This could be the reason `$table->foreign('course_id')->references('course_id')->on('ptable');  which is wrong  but`  $table->foreign('course_id')->references('level_id')->on('ptable');` is correct