# Migrate php aritsan laravel 5.2 [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S01]

Tags: php, laravel, migrate, laravel-artisan

I have a problem with the migration command laravel .

I have added entities with foreign Llaver and now he throws me an error .

[ PDOException ]
  SQLSTATE [ 42S01 ] : Base table or view already exists : 1050 Table ' Administrators' already exists

Before performing an update or something but did not throw errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 Error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already)

Answer (score 0):

first delete the tables
then run `composer update`
then `php artisan migrate`