# PHP artisan migrate command giving errors?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when I run the command `php artisan migrate` it results in the following error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create
>   table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
>   `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
>   `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
>   `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default
>   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
```

I am using Laravel 5.4 on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older

Answer (score 1):

It's letting you know that the 'Users' table exists already - when you're running your migration - it's trying to create that (but it already exists)

This is generally because you've tried running the command 'php artisan migrate' before. This has to be rolled back to have those changes 'undone', or have the DB tables cleared out.

You can run:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

That should get rid of all the tables - then you can run

```
php artisan migrate
```

and it should load everything appropriately.

The alternative approach? Log into your DB and physically drop those tables from the DB. Then you can run the migrate again and it will work.

***A little gotcha:*** Check your migration first though: it should have this function:

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

If it doesn't, the rollback won't drop the users table and you'll still have this issue (which means you'll have to log into the DB and drop the tables manually).

If you create the migration with this command, the rollback functionality will be included automatically:

```
php artisan make:migration create_yourtablename_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the exact code in that question then I can see a simple spelling error

```
email varchar(255) not n ull,
```

I know its silly answer given by me.
but you can use:

```
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan migrate:reset
```

And better use this. Probably it will work:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

### Follow These steps to [migrate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations)

Check you database 
if there is 'users' table exits then `DROP`users`table`

> Now

**Step 1.** To create a migration, use the make:migration
command :- `php artisan make:migration create_yourtablename_table`

**Step 2.** Type this command : `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , what i did was comment out lines in *(up function)* in **users and password_reset migration** and then i tried it worked. I dont know whether it is right approach ! correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Answer from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21100.

Your Problem can be Solved
by Changing create_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //Add this line
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```