# laravel migration does not working

Tags: laravel, migration

[image]I previously created users table. Now I have created a new migration to create a new books table inside my schema. When I try to run the command

php artisan migrate
it shows me:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>       SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
>       ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
>       ement primary key, `username` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) n
>       ot null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0
>       not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set
>       utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

My question is just the same as [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older) and codes i ran are same as well.
So, i have tried all the solutions suggested here.But they don't work for me.As i can't make comments on the post i have to post it as a new question.Hope you will realise my concern and help me out.

Comment: Share the migration code. It seems you are creating `users` table again.

Comment: i think you didnt create the users table from the migration table. check your migration table. or run `php artisan migrate:status` in ur terminal.

Comment: Here is my migration table code:
      public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('task', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->text('body');
                $table->increments('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
    }

Comment: No, i have created another two tables named "task" and "introduction". @MilanChheda

Comment: The cause of this problem is that `users` table exists in your database but, there isn't the record of it in your `migration` table.  I want to see a result of `php artisan migrate:status`. Could you show me it?

Comment: i've added the result @Yujiro

Answer (score 5):

As your screenshot shows, none of your migrations have actually run.  You must have created the `users` table manually, or maybe you did run a migration but it somehow got messed up.

If you don't mind losing whatever data is in the tables, the simplest fix is (**you will lose all data in your tables!**):

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

which will rollback all migrations, and run them fresh again.

[More info in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#rolling-back-migrations).

Comment: "...or maybe you did run a migration but it somehow got messed up." that reminded me of my issue, this is what happened for me; i ran the migration but it got interrupted, but now when i run the migration it says the table exists, so i realize that the first table of this migration batch has been created already. so, as the solution, i dropped that specific table and ran migration again, it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the result!

In that case, you may delete all table, and redo `php artisan migrate`.

If you would not feel like doing it, you can insert a record of migration file name which was created already to your `migrations` table as well and then run `php artisan migrate`.

In that case, you don't need to delete tables.

For example, you seem to created `users` table, so please insert record whose `migration` is `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table` like following.

[image]

then, when you run `php artisan migrate:status`, you will get the result as follows.

[image]

if this is the case, if you run `php artisan migrate`, `migration` file later `2014_10_12_200000_create_password_resets_table` will be execute.

In this way, you should insert the record of `migration` file name which is created already, and then run `php artisan migrate`, it will work well!

**P.S.**

As @mschuett says in [Laravel Migration table already exists but i want to add new not the older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older), your `migrations` table is messed up.

Because, you have `users` table in your database, but migration of `2014_10_12_00000_create_users_table` isn't executed.

If there are multiple migration files, if you run it and it fails somewhere, the `migration` status have been `Y` to where you ran.

Comment: I've deleted all the database from mysql and then when i ran php artisan migrate it only shows user and reset password tables. The other tables which i created manually they are not in mysql database.

Comment: "php artisan migrate:status" that command is new for me and i think it is very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan migrate:refresh` will delete all data and recreates tables, while `migrate` just creates tables what doesn't exist yet.

In case to refresh only some tables, (if migrate doesn't work so), helped me to delete those tables and table rows in migrations table and further successfully do `php artisan migrate`. 
(yet tried only on 4.2, but it may work on upper versions too)