# what's wrong when i try to migrate?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I just start to learn laravel as an online course and do all instructions step by step behind the instructor but when I try to make migrate I get an error and doesn't migrate to database. what's wrong?

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

In Connection.php line 449:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What's the error???

Comment: you have to provide the error and the code used, otherwise, there is no way we can help you

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: there is screenshot attachment show the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLMOR.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration table already exists but i want to add new not the older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older)

Comment: Try `php artisan migrate:reset`

Comment: Nothing to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your data base and delete the table users and then re-do : php artisan migrate

Comment: i did that but invain

Comment: Mmm okay you can try this: php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: As the same problem as well as Nothing to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

you need refresh your database this error becouse users table in your DB please Go to your terminal and run this commend

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

or go to your phpmyadmin and drop your tables on DB to run your migrations from scratch using this commend after drop your DB

```
 php artisan migrate
```

congratulations ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete Users table(all tables excepted migration if there is an entry in migration table truncate migration table)
2. run composer dump command.
3. run php artisan migrate.

**enjoy :)**