# I want to run the php artisan migrate command but I get an error

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have a project and I want to migrate the database files, but when I try to run the PHP artisan migrate command I get an error

I did a lot of searches, but I didn't get any useful results, please help me

it is my database file code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBlogTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blogs');
    }

}
```

and it is an error message

```
Migrating: 2022_07_12_122514_create_blog_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "blogs" already exists (SQL: create table "blogs" ("id" integer
not null primary key autoincrement, "user_id" integer not null, "name" varchar not null, "text" varchar not null, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime))

  at C:\Users\Modiran\Desktop\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

    716▕     }


  1   C:\Users\Modiran\Desktop\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:495
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "blogs" already exists")

  2   C:\Users\Modiran\Desktop\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:495
      PDO::prepare("create table "blogs" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "user_id" integer not null, "name" varchar not null, "text" varchar not null, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)")
```

Comment: `table "blogs" already exists` is fairly self-explanatory. You can either go into your database and drop the table, or comment all of that out while you run the migration, and make sure to uncomment it when you're done.

Comment: So, table already exists. If you wish to rollback all the changes you have made and do a fresh install, do `php artisan migrate:rollback` and if you wish to undo only the last step, do `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration table already exists, but I want to add new not the older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077458/laravel-migration-table-already-exists-but-i-want-to-add-new-not-the-older)

Comment: Be careful - if your `blogs` table contains real data that you want to keep, you need to back it up before dropping (or don't drop it)!

Answer (score 1):

You can run "php artisan migrate:fresh" the existing table will be dropped automatically and regenerate the table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, the table already exists.

This can happen when the first time you run the migration it runs into an error after having created the table.

Easiest way to solve this is to log into your database and drop the table manually and then run the migration again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi so basically i guess you have created the table(blogs) before and probably you dropped the table(blogs) to run it again.

I want you to know that every time you create a new table it also goes to migrations table.

So in this case.

1. Be very sure you dropped the table
2. Then open the migrations table and delete the row for blogs

Then you're good to go.