# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. Can you help me?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

Can you help me?

**I use the MySQL.**

I make

```
php artisan migrate
```

but error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `learn`.`products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
>   constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add
>   constraint `products_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`)
>   references `categories` (`id`))

`Categories` migration:

```
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

`Products` migration:

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 150)->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('image', 255);
        $table->boolean('sale')->default(false);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
```

Comment: It's because of a type mismatch between your `products.category_id` column and your `categories.id` column. You either need to make your `id` columns `bigIncrements` or make your `category_id` an `->integer('category_id')->unsigned()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error: 1005 Can't create table - Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999161/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1005-cant-create-table-laravel-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');`

With: `$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();`

*OR*

Replace: `$table->increments('id');`

With: `$table->bigIncrements('id');`

In both tables (but at least in your categories table).

---

**WHY?:**

From the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. **The size and sign of integer types must be the same**. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

From the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#columns

> **$table->increments():** Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column.
>
> **$table->unsignedBigInteger():** UNSIGNED BIGINT equivalent column.

---

So in your case:

`$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');` => UNSIGNED BIGINT

`$table->increments('id');` => UNSIGNED INTEGER.

They don't match.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very descriptive answer.